# My villagers aren't breeding. What should I do?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I may have hit them maybe like 2 or 3 times accidentally but I kept trading and nothing happened. I'm playing the Xbox 360 version of the game.

Comment: Maybe you should add some funky music? You know, set the mood?

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what your problem is? For example, you may want to include the setting that they are in (ie. a village, a room with doors). Also, is trading with them or breeding your problem? You seem to ask both questions.

Answer (score 3):

Trading isn't a way of breeding. You might mean new trades. But if you want to do breeding, you have to follow the instructions below [note that hitting villagers doesn't effect trades or breeding, only your village disposition]:

1. Make a house, or use an old house. You'll need to build a village house which is the first step of breeding. This is so the new villagers will have a place to live in. It must have the following:

   - Walls [Used for protection. Prevents mobs from coming in and out.]
   - Doors [Used for a villager to enter and exit. Make sure it's blocked to prevent villagers from coming in and out for this time until breeding is finished. You need more doors than villagers.]
   - Roofs [According to Mojang, it's used to prevent sunlight from coming in. You can use torches, glowstone, or any other light source except for the sunlight to light the house up. Lighting is to prevent mobs from spawning.]

Your "house" should be like this:

[image: Village houses example]

If you're not building a house, use a normal already spawned.

2. Put 2 villagers in. 2 villagers is enough for breeding to happen. Make sure they don't get out. This is why I told you in step one to blocks the doors. You can put any type of villager inside. Doesn't matter why type and what it wears [Which means you can put a Cleric and a Tool Smith or others inside!].
3. Wait for it to happen. This may be the boring part, but wait till you see a baby villager pop out. When it does, you're done doing the breeding process! It takes 20 minutes for a baby villager to turn into an adult. This is a good way to increase the population of villagers. This might also mean more villagers to breed! But this isn't the last step!
4. Repeat. That's right! If you want more, do it again! Since you already built or have a villager house, skip step 1 and do the other step all over again! get 2 more villagers in the house without escaping, wait and then you have another new villager.

So that's how you do breeding. Have fun building, trading, fighting, and of course, breeding!

Comment: Someone edited the post with offernsive words and luckily it was rejected.